# How to enable USB Debugging on Linux with a chinese branded tablet?

Tags: android, linux, usb, adb, virtualbox

When I was setting up everything for my Android development in a **Linux Virtual Machine (Oracle Virtual Box)**, I ran into the problem that Linux **was not recognizing** my GENESIS Tablet.

Despite it's not an official development device, I believe almost any device should work since we know their VendorID's and ProductID's.

Then I found some very useful guides on the web, such as:

1 - http://binglongx.wordpress.com/2013/03/05/use-android-devices-for-guest-ubuntu-os-in-virtualbox-on-windows-7-host/

or even

2 - http://esausilva.com/2010/05/13/setting-up-adbusb-drivers-for-android-devices-in-linux-ubuntu/

---

And...
Yes! I followed all the steps correctly, however, Linux still doesn't recognize my Android tablet.

1 - VendorID and ProductID were defined as a filter. (Yes, I tried to remove all the unnecessary fields but it was worthless).

[image]

2- And also I modify the 51-android-rules.

[image]

3 - And that's what I get.

[image]

---

Everything should be working fine but unfortunately is not. So that's it. I would appreciate any help and honestly hope it someday will help someone either.

Kind Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I've been struggling to solve this for a while. I found out that the problem was all about the Virtual Machine.
I did all the same steps on Linux (dual-boot) and it worked.

If you are developing for an unknown branded tablet device make sure you modify the 51-android.rules file. It's usually the main problem when it comes about identifying the USB device.